# Redirecting the domain to a new subfolder (website and localhost)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to move all my files to a subfolder

For the moment :

```
- CssFolder1
- ScriptFolder2
- OtherFolder3
- Index.php
- File1.php
- File2.php
- File3.php
- File4.php
- File5.php
```

After :

```
- CssFolder1
- ScriptFolder2
- OtherFolder3
- FileFolder
    - Index.php
    - File1.php
    - File2.php
    - File3.php
    - File4.php
    - File5.php
```

How I can redirect my localhost (and website) to the subfolder ?

> localhost/mywebsite/FileFolder/dashboard.php  **----->**
>   localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php

Thank you

Comment: you can use .htaccess file on root to redirect your requests to the files inside the specified directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your .htaccess file.

I assume that you use Apache web server, not nginx.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)FileFolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ FileFolder/$1 [L]
```

If you want to use redirect codes you may use the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/FileFolder/(.*)$ http://**yourdomain**/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's work great ! But I can change the error message "**Not Found 
The requested URL /mywebsite/FileFolder/file_dont_exist.php was not found on this server.**" ? (because i want users do not see the tree)

Comment: You can add a blank index.html file in your folder or add `Options -Indexes` to a new line of your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I add index.html (blank) in FileFolder, and my htaccess look like `Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)FileFolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ FileFolder/$1 [L]` But I have the same page (Page not Found ...)